# Design choice of existing code; Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I want to ask a question about an abstract factory that I have implemented but am in doubt of the best design choice. My question is about should I have a design that requires addition of new make methods to the factory interface when extension is called upon, or should I use a generic approach that eliminates changes to the factory interface but requires an (ugly but runtime verified) down cast.

Now, should I ask this question on Programmers.SE or on CodeReview.SE?

Answer (score 9):

if you post the Code on Code Review (following the guidelines for CodeReview questions) we will be more than happy to help you optimize for performance, or readability, or other things like that.

Program design sounds more like a question for Programmers than it does for code review.

Code Review likes to hammer out syntax and ways to make your design work.  if it's a bad design then the code will probably look like a blob.

deciding what the design should be and what design is going to work best sounds like Programmers to me, but if you have working code that you want reviewed, Code Review might (small chance) point you toward a new design choice, just depends on the code and functionality you are looking for.

if you do post on CR and/or Programmers please comment on my answer with the links.

[Here is the link to on-topic questions on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

and this does say

> Best practices and design pattern usage

AND

> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question about …
>
> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")

Answer (score 6):

Your question sounds more like a Code Review question than a Programmers one, but you could try posting it in both sites. However you should take care to  target each site's audience:

- Code Review only accepts questions that include *working code*, reviewing code isn't exactly a pleasant experience if the damn thing doesn't compile.

  If your code is relatively small and its working, you should go ahead and post there. If it isn't working, then perhaps you should start by posting a question on Stack Overflow.
- On Programmers, code isn't necessary. If you think a small piece of code would help clarify your question, then by all means include it, but ideally the question should stand without the code.

  What we are more interested in hearing is what your specific problem is, and what design choices you've already considered. If you've already dismissed an approach or two, please tell us why.

Answer (score 0):

Post to Code Review, and if you don't get enough response after some time and bounty then post to Programmers.

This is suited to Code Review but that site has much lower traffic than Programmers, which can mean you won't get a useful response.

Comment: there is a lot of Traffic on CR and getting a `useful response` that is very much an opinion probably based on a bad experience

Comment: @Malachi Hm, Kirk's opinion on CR's responses seems to be supported by the available data: ["There are, at the time of this writing, 1237 questions without any upvoted answers, a whopping 1010 of which have absolutely no answers at all. That’s over 10% of the site’s questions, sitting untouched and barely considered to be alive."](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-is-code-review-doing-right-now)

Comment: That doesnt mean that the responses that you get are not useful.

Comment: My suggestion was to try the responses on CR first. That's the only sensible approach.

Comment: @YannisRizos That was then, [this is now](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission)

Comment: I've been following that thread @SimonAndréForsberg, and I've been (very slowly) going through my tags on CR and trying to help. Unfortunately, my time is extremely limited these days. Hopefully, this call of duty will be more successful than the [last one](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/612/4673).